# Is there a way to merge 41 nc files into one file?

Tags: r, netcdf

I have 41 nc files, all containing climate data for 41 separate years. Is there a way to merge these files together on r?

Comment: should state that I am pretty new to this type of work

Comment: What are nc files?

Answer (score 1):

The `stars` package will do just that (and much more): [Reading datasets from multiple files](https://r-spatial.github.io/stars/articles/stars1.html#reading-datasets-from-multiple-files).

A simple Google search will also give you lots of info and tutorials using the `raster` package ([for example](https://pjbartlein.github.io/REarthSysSci/raster_intro.html)).

Answer (score 1):

While you have tagged R, this is very easily done on the command line using CDO. As simple as:

```
cdo mergetime *.nc out.nc
```